# Opencart doesn't displays products

Tags: opencart

I have OpenCart 1.5.6.4 installed on a server, and I have imported a database with over 64,000 products. They are all being displayed on the admin pannel, I can edit them, but on the front there apper to be none. If I add a new product it will be displayed. I have already checked the database an all the values of the new products are similar to the old one but. I have also changed the theme. Nothing happend

So they are displayed on the admin pannel, but not on the front, what am I missing?

Comment: Check in you admin panel of category assigned, quantity > 0 and enable product option.

Answer (score 0):

Check your product_to_store table. If it's empty, you just need to write a small script to add the product IDs to the correct store (usually ID 0)